# ideas for using a closed stair

Tags: stairs, old-house, closet

This is a 300 years old building split into multiple apartments in the middle of Lisbon. When doing some cleaning (removing some cover tables), what supposed to be a "small" cubicle/closet turns out to be the old access to the top of the building and isis 3 times bigger.

The flat needs some construction work/renovations but now with this weird finding and trying to take more advantage of the space (flat is only 40m2) ideas about needed, below some pictures:

Any ideas about how to take advantage of this space are more than welcome.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't an appropriate question for this site, as there is no possibility of there being a "Single Correct Answer". However, feel free to discuss it in chat.

Answer (score 1):

My 6 year old grandson would love to make a “fort” there...

Answer (score 1):

**Access the top of the building.**

A funky semi-vertical closet does not let you charge much extra rent.  But if this tenant has private access to a rooftop patio that is huge extra value.  She can have potted plants, deck chairs, maybe a grill.

If you do not want her on the roof, open the top of the stairs to the roof and cover it with a skylight.  Paint the stairs with water resistant paint.  She can use the stairs as a solarium / grow room.